# Canvas to png not working fabricjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, fabricjs

This is my code to export canavs to Image using FabricJS:

```
$("#canvas2png").click(function(){
    canvas.isDrawingMode = false;

    if(!window.localStorage){alert("This function is not supported by your browser."); return;}
    // to PNG
    window.open(canvas.toDataURL('png'));
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ridwanamirsene/nL4jbLon/1/

why when i click canvas 2 png button.. it's not working..

it wonrking sample http://jsfiddle.net/softvar/9hrcp/ by softvar

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just a cross domain problem with your images:

> VM71 fabric.min.js:3 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute
>   'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be
>   exported.(…)

**[CORS enabled image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image)**

> What is a "tainted" canvas?
>
> Although you can use images without CORS
>   approval in your canvas, doing so taints the canvas. Once a canvas has
>   been tainted, you can no longer pull data back out of the canvas. For
>   example, you can no longer use the canvas toBlob(), toDataURL(), or
>   getImageData() methods; doing so will throw a security error.

I changed your initialize method:

```
initialize: function(src) {
        this.image = new Image();
        this.image.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
        this.image.src = src;
         this.image.onload = (function() {
            this.width = this.image.width;
            this.height = this.image.height;
            this.loaded = true;
            this.setCoords();
            this.fire('image:loaded');
            canvas.renderAll(paper); 
        }).bind(this);
    },
```

and I have used an enabled cors image from wikimedia:

```
var imgs = [

    'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0e/American_Black_Bear_%283405475634%29.jpg', // cat
    'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0e/American_Black_Bear_%283405475634%29.jpg' // mouse
];
```

now [your forked fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fwgkwrLf/) works.